# JavaScript: Add increasing number to name attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm creating an HTML table from data pulled from an XML file using JQuery. This data is to be posted via HTTP POST somewhere else.

When the XML contains multiple items (i.e. songs), it creates the respective HTML but the `name` attribute of the `input` elements stays the same.

This is the JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.get('test.xml', function(d){
        $('body').append('<form id="myForm" action="http://myendpoint.xyz/test" method="post" target="_blank" />');
        $('#myForm').append('<div id="mySongs" />');
        $('#mySongs').append('<input type="submit" value="Submit">');

        $(d).find('song').each(function() {

            var $song = $(this); 
            var title = $song.find('title').text();
            var artist = $song.find('artist').text();
            var price = $song.find('price').text();
            var currency = $song.find('currency').text();

            var html = '<div id="mySongs"> <span id="title"><input type="text" name="title" value="' + title + '" /></span>';
            html += '<span id="artist"><input type="text" name="artist" value="' + artist + '" /></span>';
            html += '<span id="price"><input type="text" name="price" value="' + price + '" /></span>';
            html += '<span id="currency"><input type="text" name="currency" value="' + currency + '" /></span>';
            html += '</div>';

            $('#mySongs').append($(html));

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The HTML code produced after pulling the XML data and running the above code looks currently this way:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://myendpoint.xyz/test" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div id="mySongs">  
        <span id="title">
            <input type="text" name="title" value="Song Number 1"></span>
        <span id="artist">
            <input type="text" name="artist" value="Artist Number 1"></span>
        <span id="price">
            <input type="text" name="price" value="25.00"></span>
        <span id="currency">
            <input type="text" name="currency" value="EUR"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="mySongs">
        <span id="title">
            <input type="text" name="title" value="Song Number 2"></span>
        <span id="artist">
            <input type="text" name="artist" value="Artist Number 2"></span>
        <span id="price">
            <input type="text" name="price" value="30.00"></span>
        <span id="currency">
            <input type="text" name="currency" value="USD"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like to add an increasing number to the `name` attribute so that when multiple items are pulled, the code shows the respective number to identify it (For example: `name="title[1]"`).

I would like the HTML to look as shown below instead:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://myendpoint.xyz/test" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div id="mySongs">  
        <span id="title">
            <input type="text" name="title[1]" value="Song Number 1"></span>
        <span id="artist">
            <input type="text" name="artist[1]" value="Artist Number 1"></span>
        <span id="price">
            <input type="text" name="price[1]" value="25.00"></span>
        <span id="currency">
            <input type="text" name="currency[1]" value="EUR"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="mySongs">
        <span id="title">
            <input type="text" name="title[2]" value="Song Number 2"></span>
        <span id="artist">
            <input type="text" name="artist[2]" value="Artist Number 2"></span>
        <span id="price">
            <input type="text" name="price[2]" value="30.00"></span>
        <span id="currency">
            <input type="text" name="currency[2]" value="USD"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

How to achieve this? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use the index argument of `each` callback:

```
$(d).find('song').each(function(i) {

     var html = '<div...> <span..><input name="title['+ i +']" value="' + title + '" /></span>'

});
```

Comment: @charlietfl Works like a charm. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can write

`title[]` instead `title[1]`

and server automaticaly set indexes.

Comment: This. So much better in every possible way.

Comment: @Artemiy StagnantIce Alexeew Yes, this is a good one. Thank you. I had tried it but currently I need the numerator in the HTML (at least for the moment)

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
var idx = 0;
$(d).find('song').each(function () {

    var $song = $(this);
    var title = $song.find('title').text();
    var artist = $song.find('artist').text();
    var price = $song.find('price').text();
    var currency = $song.find('currency').text();

    var html = '<div id="mySongs"> <span id="title"><input type="text" name="title[' + idx + ']" value="' + title + '" /></span>';
    html += '<span id="artist"><input type="text" name="artist[' + idx + ']" value="' + artist + '" /></span>';
    html += '<span id="price"><input type="text" name="price[' + idx + ']" value="' + price + '" /></span>';
    html += '<span id="currency"><input type="text" name="currency[' + idx + ']" value="' + currency + '" /></span>';
    html += '</div>';

    $('#mySongs').append($(html));
    idx++;
});
```

Comment: Why? Just have `.each(function (idx)`

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual this works also. I just tested it. Thank you very much as well Ricardo!

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual Hi Ricardo, I did not down-vote. I still don't have the rights to up-vote or down-vote yet.